# Add html column in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a HTML backup report from Windows Serve Backup logs. This reports returns the latest logs with the properties:

1. TimeCreated
2. ID
3. Level Display
4. Message

My script is:

```
$lastsevendays = (get-date) - (new-timespan -day 7)
$MyObject = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName='Microsoft-Windows-Backup'; StartTime=$lastsevendays}

$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
"@ 

$MyObject | Select 'TimeCreated', 'LevelDisplayName','ID', 'Message' | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header | Out-file C:\script.htm
```

Now i want to add a column on the right of the column "message". Typically this column will return the size of the backup. I can have the backup size with the following command:

```
(($objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Backup").Size) / 1MB)
```

I have been looking for days but i cannot really see a way. 
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated properties would be helpful.  The general format follows:

```
@{ Name = "PropertyNameHere"; Expression = { <# Code to define property value here, using $_ as the current object #> }}
```

Example in your scenario.  I assume you define $objFSO ahead of time.  Note that there are probably better ways for you to pull the size.

```
#Everything on one line!
    $MyObject |
        Select 'TimeCreated', 'LevelDisplayName','ID', 'Message', @{ Name = "BackupSize"; Expression = { (($objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Backup").Size) / 1MB) }} |
        ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header |
        Out-file C:\script.htm

#### #### #### #### ####

#Alternative:  Define calculated property hash(es) ahead of time
    $BackupSize = @{ Name = "BackupSize"; Expression = { (($objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Backup").Size) / 1MB) } }

    $MyObject |
        Select 'TimeCreated', 'LevelDisplayName','ID', 'Message', $BackupSize |
        ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header |
        Out-file C:\script.htm
```

Another example adding a column that always has the value 42, and another that looks at the value of the first item in the events properties property:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName System -MaxEvents 5 |
    Select TimeCreated, Id, @{ Name = "StaticProperty"; Expression = {42}}, @{ Name = "Property1"; Expression = {$_.Properties[0].value}}
```

A few example resources:

- http://www.jasonhelmick.com/2010/11/28/fun-with-calculated-properties-for-reports-2/
- http://stevenmurawski.com/powershell/2009/04/tip-calculated-properties
- http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/29/name-that-property/
- http://learn-powershell.net/2014/01/24/avoiding-system-object-or-similar-output-when-using-export-csv/

If you find yourself using these often, and you use the PowerShell ISE 3 or later, add a snippet!  This is by far the most used snippet in my collection

```
New-IseSnippet -Title "Calculated Property" -description "Create a calculated property" -text '@{ label = ""; expression = {} }' -Author Blah -CaretOffset 12 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -force
```

Cheers!