# Powershell - How do I get expanded properties and normal in one round?

Tags: powershell

I've got a fileserver, where the files are saved in a crypted name. Now I'd like to do something like that:

```
Get-Item ABB667687BB581070240D48958F3BB0696921F09 | fl *

    PSChildName       : ABB667687BB581070240D48958F3BB0696921F09
    PSIsContainer     : False
            VersionInfo       : File:            \\XYZ\ABB667687B581070240D48958F3BB0696921F09
            InternalName:     Setup.exe
            OriginalFilename: Setup.exe
            FileVersion:      5,2,0,2946
            FileDescription:  Evernote Installation Package
            Product:          Evernote®
            ProductVersion:   5,2,0,2946
            ...continuing

    BaseName          : ABB667687BB581070240D48958F3BB0696921F09
    Mode              : -a---
    Name              : ABB667687BB581070240D48958F3BB0696921F09
    Length            : 83157856
    ...continuing
    LastAccessTime    : 05.03.2014 08:23:58
```

When I try with following

```
get-Item ABB667687BB581070240D48958F3BB0696921F09 | Select-Object -Expand VersionInfo | fl *

CompanyName        : Evernote Corp., 305 Walnut Street, Redwood City, CA 94063
FileVersion        : 5,2,0,2946
ProductVersion     : 5,2,0,2946
ProductName        : Evernote®
```

Now I would like to combine PSCHild, Product, Product Version, Fileversion, LastAccessTime. How can I do that?

Tried it with something like:

```
Get-Item ABB667687BB581070240D48958F3BB0696921F09 | ft -property @{n="Filename" ; e={$_.pschildname}}, @{n="Fileinformation";e={get-Item ABB667687BB581070240D48958F3BB0696921F09 | Select-Object -Expand VersionInfo | ft product}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, You could absolutely use a solution similar to Kayasax's.

Personally, I find [calculated properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22726528/3067642) very helpful.  Other solutions such as Add-Member also work.  [This is a decent reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh750381.aspx) on the different options.

With that being said, here is a snippet of code covering a little of what you want (tweak as needed):

```
#Show Fullname, Name, and a few nested VersionInfo props for an object.
Get-Item 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe' |
    Select-Object -Property FullName,
        Name,
        @{ label = "CompanyName"; expression = {$_.VersionInfo.CompanyName} },
        @{ label = "FileVersion"; expression = {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion} },
        @{ label = "ProductVersion"; expression = {$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion} },
        @{ label = "ProductName"; expression = {$_.VersionInfo.ProductName} }

<#  Output

    FullName       : C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
    Name           : iexplore.exe
    CompanyName    : Microsoft Corporation
    FileVersion    : 11.00.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
    ProductVersion : 11.00.9600.16384
    ProductName    : Internet Explorer
#>
```

Lastly, as a word of warning, you should rarely if ever use Format-Table (ft).  This generates unusable text for your viewing only.  You might see it in verbose output, but if you ever plan to use the data again, you should not be using Format-Table.  Google around for many discussions on the topic : )

Cheers!

Comment: thanks.. I've gt that in mind ;). But thanks reminding me again. I try again and again to rarely use ft :)

Answer (score 1):

powershell allows to expand only **one** property at a time.
you cant do what you want in one "round".
What you can do is create a new psobject like that :

```
$file=ls c:\temp\putty.exe
$inf=$file |select -expand versioninfo
$myobj="dummy" | select child,product,version,write

$myobj.product=$inf.ProductName
$myobj.version=$inf.ProductVersion
$myobj.child=$file.PSChildName
$myobj.write=$file.LastWriteTime
```

Comment: thanks your solution is also one, but "cookie monsters" is a little bit more what I want :) thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tee-Object, along with calculated properties. Suppose you want to get those values from PowerShell.exe. Then, do it this way:

```
gi $PSHOME\powershell.exe | 
    tee -var pow | 
    select name, 
        @{n='Product';e={$pow.versioninfo.productname}}, 
        @{n='Product Version';e={$pow.versioninfo.productversion}}, 
        @{n='FileVersion';e={$pow.versioninfo.fileversion}}, 
        lastaccesstime | 
    fl
```

Comment: didn't know, that I can use tee in that way, too. At the moment I **don't** get a result, have to take a look if it would work also.